# firebase function deploy fail, but logs are confusing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

firebase function deploy fail, but logs are confusing. Actually, logs does not provide useful info.
I have tried renaming the functions 3 times, but no luck. This is annoying.

```
/**
 * Get random number
 * @param {number} min
 * @param {number} max
 * @return {number} random
 */
function between(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (max - min) + min
  );
}

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

exports.sendSMS2=functions.pubsub.schedule("46 7 * * *")
    .timeZone("America/New_York").onRun((context) =>{
      return client.messages
          .create({body: text +" " +between(1, 10), from: from, to: to})
          .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
```

console:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    sendSMS2(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with you're code, but just to help you (since the console will never tells you where is the problem) when I stuck like that, I comment all the code then start deploy with parts of it, until you reach to a point where the error comes in.(Comment all the code in `sendSMS2` then deploy it, if deployed successfully, try only `console.log`, then try to uncomment part of your code, and so on). Moreover, sometimes the console tells you that you can find the logs in a file, something like pubsub-debug.log. It's not that big of a help, but you need to start somewhere.

Comment: here is the full log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUncBXLrcrz-qxLyckkkLN9aqZY0Mocq/view?usp=sharing. please help

Comment: This is the error `HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Any resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App Engine region. Location must equal us-east1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in us east1.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT" }}`..However, pubsub functions don't need to activate app engine, so try to change the region by using `.region('us-east1')` (but don't forget to deleted it first if you deployed it before from firebase console->functions). Maybe with that also try to remove `.timeZone("America/New_York")`

Comment: it does not work. ```exports.sendSMS4=functions.region("us-east1").pubsub.schedule("46 7 * * *")
    .onRun((context) =>{
      return client.messages
          .create({body: text +" " +between(1, 10), from: from, to: to})
          .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
    });
``` see new log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OC1GzCLOErs0Yxu-XyQoar5pv1L3ie5D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You still get the same error, really I'm not sure why is that, maybe its related to the configuration of your project, try to investigate more on this error.

Comment: yeah. even firebase customer support service also does not know the root cause.